# json-decode two feed sources

Tags: php, json

I am try to decode two different json feed urls and merge into one oject/output. I have tried the below, however, not really having much luck.

```
feed source 1: http://sourcesample.com/feed/posts
data: [
{
name: "Me",
url: "http://example.com/sample",
title: "Sample Title",
}
]
feed source 2: http://differentsource.com/feed/details
data: [
{
 likes: "200",
 shares: "300",
 total: "1000",
}
]

$sources =array("http://sourcesample.com/feed/posts", "http://differentsource.com/feed/details");
$requests = file_get_contents($sources[0],$sources[1]);
$response = json_decode($requests);
foreach($response->data as $item){
echo'<li>'.$item->name.'</li><li>'.$item->shares.'</li>'
```

Printing the name works, but when trying to print the second object feed, nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Look [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) parameters.

Comment: file_get_contents doesn't accept multiple files

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` won't return more than one URL's contents at a time. The second parameter is being treated as `true`, roughly, for the `use_include_path` parameter. For your purposes, it's irrelevant.

Anyway, only the first feed is read. It includes no "shares" data.

Even if both *were* read, the result would be:

```
'data: [
  {
    name: "Me",
    url: "http://example.com/sample",
    title: "Sample Title",
  }
]
data: [
  {
    likes: "200",
    shares: "300",
    total: "1000",
  }
]'
```

which is not a valid JSON string - it's two objects next to each other, not merged.

If you're really confident that both feeds are the same size, you can read them both (separately) then loop through them at once:

```
$names = json_decode( file_get_contents( $sources[0] ) );
$stats = json_decode( file_get_contents( $sources[1] ) );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $names->data ); ++$i )
{
  $name = $names->data[$i];
  $stat = $stats->data[$i];

  echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($name->name) . '</li><li>' . 
       htmlspecialchars($stat->shares) . '</li>';
}
```